# Parse flat file with multiple formats

Tags: parsing, flat-file, edi, filehelpers

Its been a while since Ive had to write what amounts to a custom format edi processor.  The last time I wrote one, I was an AS/400 programmer (not iSeries to give you a timeframe).  It was pretty easy, I built a structure and inspected the record type column and began processing based on the fix positions of data and record type.

Fast forward to 2012 and I have almost exactly the same requirements except I no longer have an AS/400 to make it easy.

For brevity, the first 2 columns contain a record type and the structure is based on that type.  Any suggestion on how to best handle this in c# on a web server?

Some options I have considered are filehelpers and SSIS.  I have full control over the environment so I can do pretty much anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Multi Record engine option of FileHelpers

http://www.filehelpers.com/example_multirecords.html

You must define as many record classes as different kind of lines you have and later provide a delegate that lets FileHelpers choose the right one.

There is also a Master Detail engine:

http://www.filehelpers.com/example_masterdetail.html

Last version of the library: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=51642&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt66